# Displaying google map in asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net

Based on that user latitude and longitude values i need to display his direction in map .i am saving the user latt,lan values continuously in db.

Comment: Are you storing his location multiple times? Or just updating it as he moves? You'll need to do some math using the gps coordinates on where they currently are and where you last recorded them being.

Comment: Really bad question mate. Add more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Google Maps API for this. Here is a sample of how to implement it:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=xxx" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var map = null; 
var geocoder = null;                
var address = "<%=hdnMapAddress.Value%>"; //hidden field holding address/coordinates       

showAddress = function() {
    var mapContainer = $get("<%=pnlMap.ClientID%>");
    if (mapContainer){        
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()){      
            geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();                      
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("<%=pnlMap.ClientID%>"));               
        }                    
        if (geocoder){ 
            geocoder.getLatLng(address, 
                function(point){                                                                
                    var marker = new GMarker(point);
                    if (marker){
                        map.setCenter(point, 12);                         
                        map.addOverlay(marker);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                    }                                                              
                }
            );             
        }              
    }  
}    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google Map Control](http://googlemap.codeplex.com/) (Codeplex project) and also take a look at - [google-maps-for-aspnet](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-for-aspnet/).